# sql query not working with concat and astext

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT LATITUDE,
       LONGITUDE, 
       AsText(concat(LATITUDE,',' ,LONGITUDE)) AS point 
FROM incident_google
```

query is not working for AsText

it showing result as `NULL`.

how to get the astext values.

if the problem is on concat or AStext.

i need result for this query.

now result as,

```
38.8994816000000014 -76.9785097000000036    NULL
38.9445079999999990 -77.0045459999999906    NULL
```

i need result as

```
38.8994816000000014 -76.9785097000000036    38.899481600000001476.9785097000000036
```

Answer (score 2):

`AsText()` is a special function for working with columns of the `geometry` type.

It doesn't appear that latitude and longitude are geometry type to me; they are just floats.  It should work fine if you omit `AsText()`:

```
SELECT LATITUDE,LONGITUDE, concat(LATITUDE,',' ,LONGITUDE) AS point 
    FROM incident_google
```

[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/af901/3).

Note: On the other hand, if you *are* using the geospacial extensions, you need to specify what types you are working with and what you are trying to do.  This is a rather specialized area.

Comment: i need to use this result value in a geometry class in java.if any other way for geometry functions.

Comment: another one try to use Text() rather than AsText

Comment: @AravinthaBashyam.c, in that case just use a normal SQL query to get the values, and use the appropriate Java function to convert those values to a geometry class.  How to do that would be a Java question.

Comment: @Kaii, the query above works--see the example.  It is just not what the OP wants to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Text` instead of `Astext` first before concatinating or using `CONCAT`?

```
SELECT LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,concat(Text(LATITUDE),',' ,Text(LONGITUDE)) AS point FROM incident_google
```

Comment: if any possible to convert this as geomentry.

Comment: yes using GeomFromText() - converts string into  geometry format and returns the result.  GeomFromWKB -

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned [here](https://itnext.io/playing-with-geometry-spatial-data-type-in-mysql-645b83880331) some of these functions has been deprecated. check [here](https://mysqlserverteam.com/detecting-incompatible-use-of-spatial-functions-before-upgrading-to-mysql-8-0/) for new version names.

> In newer version of MySQL (8.0+), old spatial functions like
>   GeomFromText, AsText has been deprecated and not longer works. Make
>   sure to follow this list from here onwords if you are facing issues
>   with undefined function names.